# Join, apply texture to and then re-separate objects in Blender?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I have an imported model with 4 objects. Each color(see below: blue, red, yellow, and orange) is one object. I want to apply the same texture across all these objects in a uniform fashion but have them be the same 4 separate objects. I figured one way to do this would be to join them, apply the UV map and separate them, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that or if it is possible and couldn't find an appropriate solution anywhere. Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated! Thanks in advance.

[image: How do I join and re-separate the objects]